# Importing CSV in SSIS: truncation error

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, ssis, truncation

I am importing a CSV file in SSIS having many string columns. I have set column width more than the maximum length, but still I am getting below errors

> [Input CSV File [114]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data
>   conversion for column "Functionality" returned status value 4 and
>   status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match
>   in the target code page.".
>
> [Input CSV File [114]] Error: The "Input CSV File.Outputs[Flat File
>   Source Output].Columns[Functionality]" failed because truncation
>   occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Input CSV
>   File.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Functionality]"
>   specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the
>   specified object of the specified component.
>
> [Input CSV File [114]] Error: An error occurred while processing file
>   "D:\Prateek\SSIS_UB_PWS\January.csv" on data row 236.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
>   PrimeOutput method on Input CSV File returned error code 0xC0202092. 
>   The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
>   PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
>   component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.

As a work around, I have set values to 500 or 1000 and now it is allowing me to continue, but the actual length is in double digit.

Kindly suggest what could be the possible error.

Comment: maybe the imports read the cvs file in unicode and you have defined varchar in stead of nvarchar ?

Comment: No, Unicode is not checked. Column values are in ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

Check , what is the value of the column 'Functionality' at row number 236. And then , verify what is allowed. In the advanced editor of the source, you can increase the length(if there are not any special characters) if you are loading data into a table

Comment: you can use derived column , if the data is unicode. Use (DT_STR, 50, 1252) ([ColumnName])

Comment: in case of special characters, if I take column as DT_WSTR and want to enter it into a table column with datatype Varchar()   is it possible?

Comment: No.In case of consuming special characters in sql table, you will have to change the datatype to nvarchar()

Answer (score 0):

Truncation warning appears when your source column length is bigger than destination column length, so it'll truncate the source value to fit into its destination. Could you share with us the length of the column length, and the length of destination column?

Comment: I have added an answer, it was my bad not to note that data was getting separated on basis of comma (,) within data.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error, sorry for my bad understanding of issue. 
Actually one of the column is having multiple commas (,) in data and that was getting into other columns (Text delimiter was set to ). Hence I was getting bigger values than expected in other columns as well.

Thanks for you help!